# How can I restructure a dataframe to create new column labels based on Column[se] values and then populate those new columns with Column[value] Values

Tags: python, pandas

Original Dataframe

```
 index                Date  Device  Element  Sub_Element    Value
179593 2017-11-28 16:39:00       x        y   eth_txload        9
179594 2017-11-28 16:39:00       x        y   eth_rxload       30
179595 2017-11-28 16:39:00       x        y  eth_ip_addr  x.x.x.x
179596 2017-11-28 16:39:00       x        y  description   string
```

Desired Dataframe

```
               Date  Device  Element  description eth_txload eth_rxload eth_ip_addr
2017-11-28 16:39:00       x        y       string          9         30     x.x.x.x
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Create Dataframes for each Sub_Element and merge on=['Date', 'Device', 'Element']?

Or use some df.iloc magic to create a boolean mask and apply the value to a new column?

Or maybe there is a better/more efficient way I'm missing?

Comment: can you explain the logic behind the desired output? I'm missing the conditions that go into it. Is it take `Sub Element` column and make each value it's own column?

Comment: @MattR I'm basically dealing with sensor like data, with millions of rows. The data is collected in the scheme of [collection_timestamp, device, element(system, interface, etc), sub_element(cpu, mem, load, description, etc), value(dtype specific to sub_e value)]

Comment: @MattR Element, and Sub_Element have hundreds of unique values. Ideally I would like to pop  out all of the sub_elements that are specific to a device and element, and put those on one row for readability and future masking and df iteration. Kind of like an expand and reduce operation maybe. Hope this helps and thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, given:

```
print(df)

    index                 Date Device Element  Sub_Element    Value
0  179593  2017-11-28 16:39:00      x       y   eth_txload        9
1  179594  2017-11-28 16:39:00      x       y   eth_rxload       30
2  179595  2017-11-28 16:39:00      x       y  eth_ip_addr  x.x.x.x
3  179596  2017-11-28 16:39:00      x       y  description   string
```

Then:

```
df_out = df.set_index(['Date','Device','Element','Sub_Element'])\
           .drop('index',1).unstack()['Value'].reset_index()

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
Sub_Element                 Date Device Element description eth_ip_addr eth_rxload eth_txload
0            2017-11-28 16:39:00      x       y      string     x.x.x.x         30          9
```

Comment: @MattR Thank you!  I appreciate the comment.

Comment: @ScottBoston What is the purpose of `sum(level=[0,1,2])`? Thanks!

Comment: @ScottBoston Thanks Scott, once I unpacked this and removed the .sum(level=[0,1,2]) portion this worked perfectly and processes much faster than Tad's Solution

Comment: @Evan Yes, the sum(leve) was left in there when I was developing once I dropped 'index' column I no longer needed sum(leve).  Thanks!

Comment: @TyrelBarstow I am glad Evan questioned the sum(level) stuff.  It is not needed.   Glad, this could help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it. My solution is not as "fancy" as Scott's but I broke down the steps in my logic. His solution is probably better for a plug-and-play scenario:

```
#reading in dataframe from your text
df1 = pd.read_clipboard()

# creating an untouched copy of df1 for minpulation
df2 = df1.copy()    

# dropping the duplicates of index and Date to get one row
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['index', 'Date'])

# creating a dictionary of key, value pairs for each column and value
kv = dict(zip(df2.Sub_Element, df2.Value))

# creating a datframe out of the above dictionary
new_df = pd.DataFrame(kv, index=[0])

# creating temp values to merge on
df1['tmp'] = 1
new_df['tmp'] = 1

# merging on the tmp values
output_df = df1.merge(new_df, on='tmp')

# cleaning up for the output
del output_df['Sub_Element']
del output_df['Value']
del output_df['tmp]

#output
        index      Date Device Element description eth_ip_addr eth_rxload  eth_txload 
0  2017-11-28  16:39:00      x       y      string     x.x.x.x         30   9
```

Answer (score 0):

An admittedly more SQL-like solution but avoids dealing with indexes:

```
# read in the dataframe
df = pd.read_clipboard()

# set up what we will be joining to
anchor = df[['Date','Device','Element']].drop_duplicates()

# loop through the values we want to pivot out
for element in df['Sub_Element'].unique():

    # filter the original dataframe for the value for Sub_Element
    # using the copy method avoids SettingWithCopyWarning
    temp = df[df['Sub_Element']==element].copy() 

    temp.rename(columns={'Value':element},inplace=True) #rename the header

    # left join the new dataframe to the anchor in case of NaNs
    anchor = anchor.merge(temp[['Date','Device','Element',element]],
                          on=['Date','Device','Element'],how='left')
print(anchor)
```

Output:

```
                  Date Device Element eth_txload eth_rxload eth_ip_addr description
0  2017-11-28 16:39:00      x       y          9         30     x.x.x.x string
```

Comment: This worked perfect, and I can understand flow! Thanks Tad